# How to search for shops in Android Google map application?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-maps

I am developing a navigation application which uses google maps.

I am trying to implement "shops search" with the application. I tried the following piece of code which is capable of searching for places in the map:

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(editAddress.getText().toString(), 5, 39.0, -73, 41.0, -71);
if(addresses.size() > 0)
{
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint( (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
    mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
    mapController.setZoom(12);
    mapView.invalidate();
    editAddress.setText("");
}
```

It gives correct result when the search key is "New york" or "London",
but when I search for "Starbucks" the API does not give a result.

Which API can I use for this particular requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Implement this,  **[Google Places API](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/places/)**,  into your own Google Maps application.

Have fun!

**Edit:**

Four basic Place requests are available:

- Place Searches return a list of
  nearby Places based on a user's
  location.
- Place Details requests
  return more detailed information
  about a specific Place.
- Place
  Check-ins allow you to report that a
  user has checked in to a Place.
  Check-ins are used to gauge a Place's
  popularity; frequent check-ins will
  boost a Place's ranking in your
  application's Place Search results.
- Place Reports allow you to add new
  Places to the Place service, and to
  delete Places that your application
  has added.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot.. I tried to enable Google Places Api as u mentioned. It went to a link http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/ in which I could apply for an Api invitation. How long will it take? or Can I expect it in a couple of days. Btw, can u send me an invitation if u have any .

Comment: You just have to wait and see :-) If i can get my hands on a API key ill let you know.

Comment: Hi, I have been waiting for 2-3 days and no luck so far. Do we have any other alternative?

Comment: We opened up general availability for the Places API last week. An invitation is no longer required. Just follow the steps in the docs linked above to create a project in the Google APIs console, activate the Places API on that project, and retrieve your API key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Android to find "Starbucks" or any other sort of "shops". You will need to find somebody with a suitable Web service for this. Google might have one -- I've never looked -- but it is not baked into Android.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. I was behind google places api, but still waiting for the registration. Can u suggest any service other than Google places?